# How to get a list of twitter trends

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

I have been attempting to get the twitter trends but I am unsure of how to do this with json. I also have not found any good tutorials that I am able to follow to accomplish this successfully. As of now, I have been using Hammock to get my statuses, mentions, etc. Are there any tutorials that completely describe how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the [Twitter Official API (JSON)](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/available). You can see the [example](https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/available.json).

Anyway, I found a link that may help you: [Windows Phone 7 – Asynchronous Programming](http://blog.csainty.com/2010/10/windows-phone-7asynchronous-programming.html).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use [this API method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/available), with an unauthenticated HTTP request.

Given that you are a beginner, here are some starting tips:

- [How to perform a HTTP request](http://dandesousa.com/2010/08/30/windows-phone-7-making-an-http-request/)
- [Parsing JSON with JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)